# binary tree compaction of same subtree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

Given a tree, find the common subtrees and replace the common subtrees and compact the tree.
e.g.

```
      1
     /  \
     2   3
   / |   /\
  4  5  4  5
```

should be converted to

```
      1
     /  \
     2   3
   / |   /\
  4  5   | |

  ^  ^   | |

  |__|___| |

     |_____|
```

this was asked in my interview. The approach i shared was not optimal O(n^2), i would be grateful if someone could help in solutioning or redirect me to a similar problem. I couldn't find any. Thenks!

edit- more complex eg:

```
       1
     /  \
     2   3
   / |   /\
  4  5  2  7
       /\
      4  5
```

whole subtree rooted at 2 should be replaced.

```
      1
     /  \
     2 <--3
   / |     \
  4  5      7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a single DFS traversal using a hash map from `(value, left_pointer, right_pointer) -> node` to collapse repeated occurrences of the subtree.

As you leave each node in your DFS, you just look it up in the map.  If a matching node already exists, then replace it with the pre-existing one.  Otherwise, add it to the map.

This takes O(n) time, because you are comparing the actual pointers to the left + right subtrees, instead of traversing the trees to compare them.  The pointer comparison gives the same result, because the left and right subtrees have *already been canonicalized*.

Comment: i tried to do the same thing, but "As you leave each node in your DFS, you just look it up in the map. If a matching node already exists, then replace it with the pre-existing one. Otherwise, add it to the map. " how to do it? we need to compare if whole subtree is same. are you suggesting to have a  multi-map where multiple instances of same int value can be saved?

Comment: You might want to read the last paragraph

Comment: cool got it!   thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we need to store the node values that appear in a hash table. If the tree already exists, we can iterate the tree and if a node value is already in the set of nodes and delete the branches of that node. Otherwise, store the values in a hash map and each time, when a new node is made, check if the value appears in the map.

Comment: node values can be repeated. it's not necesaary that every repeating node can be replaced. correct me if i am unable to understand your answer.